# C# - How is this technique called?

Tags: c#

I was wondering if this technique has a name - changing state methods to return this, to be able to write them in the linq way `method().method().method()`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.Add(1).Write().Add(2).Write().Add(3).Write().Add(4).Write().Subtract(2).Write();
    }
}

internal class Test
{
    private int i = 0;

    public Test Add(int j)
    {
        i += j;
        return this;
    }

    public Test Subtract(int j)
    {
        i -= j;
        return this;
    }

    public Test Write()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("i = {0}",i.ToString());
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean Fluent interface?

Comment: Note, some methods could return another object, not just `this` and still get the same effect. Generally this is about returning something that allows further chaining.

Comment: I would rather call it 'ugly code' but this is just a personal opinion.

Comment: LINQ Isn't automatically better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Method Chaining

- http://martinfowler.com/dslwip/MethodChaining.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Answer (score 9):

[Method Chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)

Comment: Funny: I thought about how I'd call this, googled it, and found it!

Answer (score 1):

Fluent API.

A lot of frameworks now supports it.